# Setting value in footer label, gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have no idea why it is supposed to be this difficult to access stuff there is in the gridview templates..

I have a footer template inside my gridview with a simple "sum" label that i need to write the sum of hours to.

How do i access this label from the server side(c#)? so i can set what my result is when clicking "calculate".

The ASP.net

```
  <FooterTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="Labeltotaltimer" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
   </FooterTemplate>´
```

One of many solutions ive tried:

```
 Label tst = (Label)GridViewrapport.FindControl("Labeltotaltimer");
```

simple fix for letting me change the label on button click??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. FindControl works only on immediate childern, so instead of calling it on GridView itself you should be calling it on specific row, that is the foorter.

```
GridViewrapport.FooterRow.FindControl("Labeltotaltimer")
```